# preg_match(): Unknown modifier '@'

Tags: php, preg-match, ereg

I used to use my function with `ereg` (check that there's one @ symbol),

`ereg("^[^@]{1,64}@[^@]{1,255}$", $email)`

but now it is deprecated. Why I am getting an error `preg_match(): Unknown modifier '@'`  when I fixed it to `preg_match("^[^@]{1,64}@[^@]{1,255}$", $email)`?

Comment: Switch to `preg_match()` as `ereg()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) around your expression.

```
preg_match("/^[^@]{1,64}@[^@]{1,255}$/", $email)
```

I strongly suggest to start reading about [PCRE pattern syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).

Comment: now it is saying `preg_match(): Unknown modifier '$' `

Comment: @Andrew Sorry, typo. I edited.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to validate an email address:

```
preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i', $email);
```

this may help you.

Comment: @Andrew can you see this?